# Angular2 register observable event handler on multiple items in queryList

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have a collection of elements to which I would like to register a single event handler. I tried to register the event handler on each element within a template like below, although the performance is not adequate and I miss a handful of these events when the length of `myLabels` is large (> 1000)

in the `.html`

```
<template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]=myLabels>
  <div #cell (mouseenter)=onMouseEnter($event)>...</div>
</template>
```

in the `.component.ts`

```
...
OnMouseEnter(event) {
  console.log('mouse entered')
}
```

Instead, I would like to register these events as an `Observable` stream.

in my `.component.ts`;

```
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChildren('cell') cells: ElementRef;
  public mouseMoves$: Observable<MouseEvent>;
  ...
  onFrameLoad(): void {
    this.mouseMoves$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.cells.nativeElement, 'mousemove');
  }
}
```

although this does not work because `this.cells` is a `QueryList`. With `QueryList.toArray()`, I get an array where I can access each `nativeElement` like `QueryList.toArray()[n].nativeElement`

How would I set up an Observable of an event for each element in `cells`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your template contains only cells, why not put a mouse move on the template:

```
<template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]=myLabels (mouseenter)=onMouseEnter($event)>
  <div #cell>...</div>
</template>
```

Or if the template does not take event listeners, wrap it in a div:

```
<div (mouseenter)=onMouseEnter($event)>
  <template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]=myLabels>
    <div #cell>...</div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I associate the event with a particular cell?

Comment: I think `event.target` sould contain the element you're looking for (or any nested element inside that element). You can eventually find the cell by checking its parents. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

Comment: As mentioned, the event.target (or is it currentTarget) will give you the element. Yet note that your original handler also didn't get the element, only the event.
If you do need to get a hold of element's data (the attached component), you might want to look into `exportAs`